# Determine if object is SPSite or SPWeb

Tags: powershell, spweb, spsite

I have a simple question, how to determine with PowerShell if a SharePoint Site is a `SPSite` object or `SPWeb`?

I get all Site followed by user but some are `SPSite`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetType()` method

```
$web.GetType().Name
```

If it is web it gives you SPWeb otherwise SPSite

**Edit**

```
$currentSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteFollowed.Uri.AbsoluteUri if($currentSite.GetType().Name -eq "SPSite" ...
```

Comment: Thanks but to test "GetType()" you need to have an object.
My problem is I want to know before instanciation if URL is SPSite or SPWeb, otherwise I had an error

Comment: $currentSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteFollowed.Uri.AbsoluteUri
                                    if($currentSite.CompatibilityLevel -eq 15){

}

It can be nice if there is no error

Comment: Yes but it's the problem, this line call an error.... It's impossible to check before if I have to create SPWeb or SPSite?

Comment: Yes but $currentSite is empty if object is not an SPSite, so GetType don't work :)

Comment: Ok in that case you can add an AND clause which check if currentSite is null or not.. if not null then go ahead with your comparison

Comment: Ok but I will still have the error :(

Comment: $currentSite = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteFollowed.Uri.AbsoluteUri = error if url is a SPWeb